# DataGrid Merging rowheaders

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

i am creating a timeplan with drag function and am using datagrids for their amazing data binding and cell selection functionality.
all works well, except now i want to have the row headers (time) only show the hours and not the half hour segments.

This is what i want:

[image: how i want it]

And This is what i get:
[image: how it looks]

Is there a way to merge the row headers without loosing the function of actual rows? I tried to just overlap the row header with another box, but this seems clunky

Comment: Perhaps you can make one row per hour and add a custom [DataGridTemplateColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) to split each cell in half-hours? Btw, whenever you have some working code, please provide a [mre] to make it easier for people to reproduce and adjust your code.

Comment: Nothing built-in in the default DG to easily achieve it&multiple ways to think of. All of which likely a lot of work. You could go via RowHeaderStyle& remove dark horz borderbrushes that cause separated appearance; based on odd/even rowindices. Still 2 row headers would remain logically.
You could use your own controltemplate adding extra 1 extra merged header region, hiding real ones. You could split each row into 2 sub-rows. 
You could align another itemscontrol left hand faking these merged headers ...

Comment: alright, i guess another box where the headers are is the easiest solution

Comment: I think you might be able to do this using Telerik radgridview but I lost interest before I found an appropriate article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i did the following:
I created a grid on the side of the rowheaders, which i filled with half as many rows as the datagrid. the first row has a set height, so it matches the height of the Datagrid header, which i do not want to scale, as it contains the week day names

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid_Datagrid_Times_box" 
             Grid.Column="1"
             Grid.Row="1"
             Grid.RowSpan="2"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Grid x:Name="Grid_Times"
           Grid.Column="0">

           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
           </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     </Grid>
     <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid_Timetable"
               Grid.Column="1"
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               ColumnHeaderHeight="30">
      ...
    </DataGrid>
```

in codebehind on Size Changed is set

```
private void Datagrid_Resize(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid DG = new DataGrid();
        if ((sender) is DataGrid)
        {
            DG = (DataGrid)sender;
        }
        double test = DG.RowHeight;
        DataGridRow rowt = GetFirstVisualChild<DataGridRow>(DG, 1);
        double testR = rowt.ActualHeight; 


        DG.RowHeight = (Grid_Datagrid_Times_box.ActualHeight-30) /    (numberOfRows);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < (numberOfRows+2); i++)
        {
            DataGridRow row = GetFirstVisualChild<DataGridRow>(DG, i);
            if (row != null)
            {
                row.FontSize = DG.RowHeight / 2.3;
                row.Height = DG.RowHeight;
            }
            foreach (UIElement ele in Grid_Times.Children)
            {
                if (ele.GetType() == typeof(TextBlock))
                {
                    TextBlock txtb = (TextBlock)ele;
                    txtb.FontSize = DG.RowHeight;
                }
            }
          }
    }
```

and

```
public static T GetFirstVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject depObj, int index) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T )
                {
                    counter++;
                    if (counter==index)
                        return (T)child;
                }

                T childItem = GetFirstVisualChild<T>(child, index);
                if (childItem != null) return childItem;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```